# c# - Accessing data in a record array

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I have 7 arrays being read in separately and then use them to combine into one array which is my "record" array.

This is my Record structure:

```
public class Record
{
    // Each of the data
    public string month;
    public int afDays;
    public int years;
    public double rainfall;
    public double sunshineHours;
    public double maxTemp;
    public double minTemp;

    // Constructor
    public Record(string newMonth, int newAfDays, int newYears, double newRainfall, double newSunshine, double newMaxTemp, double newMinTemp)
    {
        // Set the instance variables to each of the given values.
        month = newMonth;
        afDays = newAfDays;
        years = newYears;
        rainfall = newRainfall;
        sunshineHours = newSunshine;
        maxTemp = newMaxTemp;
        minTemp = newMinTemp;
    }
}
```

I wish to then search this array by using a users input 'year' and then search through this record array and display the full records of all array entries with the matching year.

This is how the record array is constructed

```
// Set the size of the record array, using the length of month - as its the       size of the data set.
recordArray = new Record[months.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < months.Length; i++)
{
    // Make a new record using each of the elements of each array.
    recordArray[i] = new Record(months[i], afDays[i], years[i], rainfall[i], sunshineHours[i], maxTemp[i], minTemp[i]);
}
```

I wish to then use a statement simillar to the following to search through the array:

```
case ConsoleKey.D4: //Search and display by Year
    Console.WriteLine("Please input a year");
    int userYear = 0;
    userYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < analyser.years.Length; i++) //unfinished
    {
       if (analyser.recordArray.years = useryears)

    }
```

Comment: Looks decent so far - what issue are you having?  What do you think should go inside the `if` statement?

Comment: Hint: `=` is for assignment; `==` is for a comparison. Next, think about how you're going to use `i` within the loop.

Comment: Well i was thinking just to only print out the current record whenever it matched the users input year so something along the lines of analyser.recordArray.years == useryears as shown above. But i get "record does not contain a definition for "years" etc...

Comment: recordArray[i].years. The entire record array doesn't have a years property. A single record from it, does.

Comment: not sure what your trying to do... but looks like your making it way harder than needed. Why do you array the items when making the new array recordArray using i. could you explain more as to what you doing...

Comment: Will attempt this @ManoDestra and report back. thanks in advance! edit: Works perfectly, thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below:

```
public class Record
{
    // Each of the data
    public string month;
    public int afDays;
    public int years;
    public double rainfall;
    public double sunshineHours;
    public double maxTemp;
    public double minTemp;

    // Constructor
    public Record(string newMonth, int newAfDays, int newYears,
        double newRainfall, double newSunshine, double newMaxTemp, double newMinTemp)
    {
        // Set the instance variables to each of the given values.
        month = newMonth;
        afDays = newAfDays;
        years = newYears;
        rainfall = newRainfall;
        sunshineHours = newSunshine;
        maxTemp = newMaxTemp;
        minTemp = newMinTemp;
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, Record> getRecords(string[] months, int[] afDays, int[] years,
        double[] rainfall, double[] sunshineHours, double[] maxTemp, double[] minTemp)
    {
        return months.Select((m, i) => new Record(months[i], afDays[i], years[i],
            rainfall[i], sunshineHours[i], maxTemp[i], minTemp[i])).ToDictionary(r => r.years);
    }
}
```

If there are multiple records with the same `years`:

```
    public static Dictionary<int, List<Record>> getRecords(string[] months, int[] afDays, int[] years,
        double[] rainfall, double[] sunshineHours, double[] maxTemp, double[] minTemp)
    {
        return months.Select((m, i) => new Record(months[i], afDays[i], years[i],
            rainfall[i], sunshineHours[i], maxTemp[i], minTemp[i])).GroupBy(r => r.years).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
    }
```